# C: Array declared inside a function

Tags: c, arrays, memory, free

When I declare an array (of structs) inside a function, is the memory freed automatically after return or do I have to free it manually?

```
mezo pre_tabla[8][8]
```

Comment: You didn't allocate. So you have nothing to free. Whoever did it will take care of the consequences too :P

Comment: If you didn't use `malloc()` or a similar call, you do not need to use `free()`. Times to be weary of this are when calling code (such as in a library) that performs an allocation that isn't obvious; read the documentation for library calls to find out your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare array statically then you don't need to free it manually. But if you allocate array dynamically (by using malloc() or calloc()) then you need to free it manually. For ex -

static declaration below:

```
struct info {
    char p;
    int x;
};

struct info arr[10];    // doesn't require to free it.
```

dynamic allocation below:

```
struct info *c;

c = malloc(sizeof(info) * 10);  // dynamic memory allocation, needs to be freed via free() system call
```

Answer (score 3):

Definition Inside function will give memory in stack which will be cleared as soon as function scope will die.Using dynamic memory allocation will need separate free call.

Answer (score 1):

If array is not declared as `static` the memory should be freed when programs leaves out of scope in which array is declared.

Comment: And if it _is_ declared as static, there's still nothing to free manually, per the question posted.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not possible to delete a static variable manually. I mean static variable will remain in the stack after function return

Answer (score 1):

All local variables/structures are allocated in stack.

When you enter the function, you have a stack pointer and addresses that are used to store data are related to it.

When you return from function, the stack pointer is updated to correspond the caller function, so it can be said, that memory is freed automatically.

```
+----------+
|          |
| f1 var1  |<--- f1() stack pointer
| f1 var2  |
| f1 arr[0]|
|  .....   |
| f1 arr[N]|
| f2 var1  |<--- f2() stack pointer
| f2 var2  |
| f1 arr[0]|
|  .....   |
| f1 arr[N]|
+----------+
```